# Android JSON Array inside Array data

Tags: android, json, arrays

Hey every one i want to get data from JSON but i could not get.. because the service come array inside array so anyone have Idea to solve, please

```
  "services":[{"main_category_id":"78","main_category_name":"Repairing",
  "product": [{"product_id":"3","product_name":"Washing Machine",
```

i have code like but only product data comes but service data exception

```
   JSONArray contentServices = dataContent
.getJSONArray("services");
JSONObject Service_items = contentServices.getJSONObject(0);
List<CompanyServicesBean> jsonServicesList = new             ArrayList<CompanyServicesBean>();
for (int j = 0; j < Service_items.length(); j++) {
JSONObject services = items.getJSONObject(j);
CompanyServicesBean serviceBean = new CompanyServicesBean();
serviceBean.setmain_category_id(services
.getString("main_category_id"));
 ServiceBean.setmain_category_name(services
 .getString("main_category_name"));
 serviceBean.setproduct_id(services
 .getString("product_id"));
 serviceBean.setproduct_name(services
.getString("product_name"));
 serviceBean.setduration_type(services                                                            .getString("duration_type"));
 serviceBean.setduration_min(services
  .getString("duration_min"));
     }
```

Comment: `Android Json Array` -> it's not Jason. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: Use an arraylist of products as a member of Category, and a separate iteration will be needed to list out the products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a services array of Json Object 
Inside each Json Object theres is another array product

So After getting services

```
for (int j = 0; j < Service_items.length(); j++) {
     JSONObject services = items.getJSONObject(j);
     CompanyServicesBean serviceBean = new CompanyServicesBean();
 }
```

You need to get product array from serviceBean Object like this

```
for (int j = 0; j < services.getJsonArray("product").length(); j++) {
     JSONObject product = items.getJSONObject(j);

 }
```

Comment: getJsonArray(String) is undefined for the type CompanyServicesBean

Comment: The CompanyServicesBean class contains a array or arraylist of product , So you should update your POJO classes